# Event notification for changes to TF Build definitions

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there any way to subscribe to notifications (service hook, SOAP, or otherwise) for when TF Build (non-XAML) build definitions are changed in TFS 2017 Update 1 On-Prem?

I have tried:

1. Subscribing to "old-style" SOAP notifications for the `BuildDefinitionChangedEvent` event type, but this only publishes notifications for changes to XAML-build definitions
2. Looked at service hooks, but there is no trigger for changes to build definitions

There is a `BuildDefinitionChangedEvent` defined in the [API contracts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/build/contracts/builddefinitionchangedevent) for the REST API and the [typings for TFS](https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk/blob/master/typings/tfs.d.ts#L390) in the VSTS Web Extension SDK. The properties for the `BuildDefinition` defined in this [contract](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/build/contracts/builddefinition) are TF Build specific, but I see no way of how I can hook into the event.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the event `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.Events.BuildDefinitionChangedEvent` in **`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi.dll`**

[image]

Then  deploy to the `Web Services\bin\Plugins` to get the BuildDefinitionChangedEvent subscriber invoked.

Comment: That library provides the .NET contracts for the Rest API. My understanding is that plug-ins only subscribe to events defined under the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.*.Server` namespaces? How would I register a plug-in to subscribe to Web Api events?

Comment: So I tested this with an `ISubscriber` implementation and it worked. Surprising giving the choice of namespace/dll for the contract. Anyway, thanks!